# Strange character escape codes produced by Gimp C-code exports

Tags: c

When I export an image from GIMP in "C source code" format, it saves the RGBA pixel bytes using octal character codes in a string. However, it is producing some odd octal escape codes for characters that I don't recognize, and I wonder if they are valid. Here's a sample:

```
  "\000\000\000\377\000\000\000\377\000\000\000\377\024-\341\377\024-\341\377\024-\341\377\000\000\000"
```

Specifically, what's with the hyphens e.g. "\024-\341"?

Is \024- or -\341 a valid octal character escape code in the C language?

Comment: No, but `\024` is, `\341` is, and `-` means `-` i.e. the same character as `\055`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By iterating through the string defined by this string literal, and printing each character in integer form, using a small test program, you can see that `\024-` is two characters: octal 024 (0x14, i.e. decimal 20, i.e. the DC4 ASCII control character), and the hyphen (decimal 45). There is no special rule for parsing a hyphen as part of such an escape.

Presumably, GIMP's algorithm for encoding these bytes chooses to avoid escapes for printable characters (perhaps to make the string literal shorter in source form).

Comment: Ah of course. As a human if I were using a string this way I'd encode all binary bytes as octal or hex escapes, but obviously printable ascii characters are entirely acceptable to represent byte values. I think I was thrown by the fact that that's the only printable character used. Thank you.